# How I can deploy my Nodejs application ReactJs Frontent with Python Backend on same domain on cpanel?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, cpanel, fastapi

I am stuck in deployment of my web app on cpanel, actually its a conversion tool!

Complete a Nodejs Application

Frontend Designed with React Js
Backend developed with Paython

I deployed frontend successfully and it's running but i dont know how to deploy python backend and connect with my frontend and how install pip dependendencies!

I need help!

I am trying to delpoy Reactjs with python backend on cpanel!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use FastAPI (Python part) with NodeJS/React. I think you need to search for a tutorial on deployment. It is too broad of a question, looks like.

Comment: I tried a lot of things but failed, thats why I am here!